# Как умножить каждый элемент CSV файла на число?

Tags: python, csv

Есть CSV файл, содержащий 8 столбцов и огромное количество строк исключительно числовых данных.

Как проще всего удвоить значение каждой ячейки?

Comment: Проще всего прочитать, умножить, записать. На каком из этапов проблема?

Comment: На этапе умножения. Как читать и редактировать файл я знаю.

Comment: print 5*7 - в чем проблема с умножением?

Comment: Я читал, как умножаются строки, столбцы и тп. Как умножить все элементы файла на число, я не нашел. На питоне я не программирую, мне нужна лишь часть его инструментала для моих задач. Изменить значения на умноженные и перезаписать файл.

Comment: У меня код есть, мне нужно лишь вписать две-три строчки, которыми можно провернуть умножение. Я их могу написать сам, вопрос в другом, как это оптимально сделать - построчно умножать или еще как-то? Достаточно было бы ссылки на любой сурс, где такой функционал представлен.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя Pandas, это исключительно просто и гораздо быстрее по сравнению с решениями, использующими циклы:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv').mul(2).to_csv('/path/to/result.csv', index=False)
```

Или, если в вашем CSV отсутствуют имена колонок:

```
(pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', header=None)
   .mul(2)
   .to_csv('/path/to/result.csv', header=None, index=False)
)
```

Если все данные не вмещаются в памяти, Pandas позволяет обработать данные по частям (chunks):

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', header=None, chunksize=10**6):
    chunk.mul(2).to_csv('/path/to/result.csv', header=None, index=False, mode='a')
```

**Тест**

Генерим тестовые данные:

```
In [80]: x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**6, 8))

In [81]: x.shape
Out[81]: (1000000, 8)

In [82]: x.head()
Out[82]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
0  0.890351  0.814333  0.436384  0.477630  0.394325  0.339082  0.205078  0.033898
1  0.749606  0.045757  0.850344  0.496043  0.727086  0.717089  0.086069  0.826920
2  0.703955  0.492983  0.105174  0.298543  0.008731  0.885632  0.233774  0.046960
3  0.053236  0.024155  0.126744  0.139082  0.475896  0.747354  0.772720  0.816470
4  0.439865  0.344010  0.301929  0.528090  0.462750  0.113415  0.621818  0.796230

In [83]: x.to_csv('c:/temp/file.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Размер `C:\Temp\file.csv` - 148MiB

Замер скорости на моем обычном (не SSD) диске:

```
In [84]: %%timeit
   ....: (pd.read_csv('c:/temp/file.csv', header=None)
   ....:    .mul(2)
   ....:    .to_csv('c:/temp/result.csv', header=None, index=False)
   ....: )
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 30.4 s per loop
```

Результат: 30 секунд на чтение исходного CSV, умножение всех элементов и запись результата обратно в CSV для 1-го миллиона строк и 8-ми столбцов

Comment: Благодарю, именно это и требовалось.

Comment: @irvis если число строк "огромное" (такое что в памяти все числа не помещаются), то файл по частям придётся обрабатывать (например, построчно—если задача ограничена производительностью диска (IO bound), то не особенно важно как вы эти строки умножите ([можете хоть по одному числу читать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024735/4279))—в целом pandas  удобна для работы с числовыми таблицами). Измерьте производительность если это важно в вашем случае.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за комментарий! Я добавил код для обработки данного случая в Pandas...

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо выполнить задачу, используя только стандартную библиотеку (иначе `pandas` [как @MaxU продемонстрировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566228/23044) идеально подходит для данной задачи):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import sys

with fileinput.FileInput(inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        try: # multiply whitespace-separated float numbers
            print(*[2*float(f) for f in line.split()]) 
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Can't parse %r line, error: %s" % (line, e), file=sys.stderr)
```

Данный код модифицирует файлы, заданные в командной строке, или stdin. Каждый исходный файл перемещается в `*.bak` файл на случай ошибки и stdout перенаправлен в исходный файл, чтобы изменения по месту производить.

Comment: Так пытался, но, честно говоря, не хватило знаний, чтобы закончить.